# Pandas does not respect conversion to time type

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, filter, time

I have this dataframe:

```
    site    date    time
1   AA  2018-01-01  0100
2   AA  2018-01-01  0200
3   AA  2018-01-01  0300
4   AA  2018-01-01  0400
5   AA  2018-01-01  0500
6   AA  2018-01-01  0600
7   AA  2018-01-01  0700
8   AA  2018-01-01  0800
9   AA  2018-01-01  0900

df.dtypes
>>>   site            object
      date    datetime64[ns]
      time            object
```

I would like to convert the `time` column to `time` type (without date) to later filter the dataframe between desired hours. So I did:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%H%M').time())
```

The dataframe now looks like this:

```
    site    date    time
1   AA  2018-01-01  01:00:00
2   AA  2018-01-01  02:00:00
3   AA  2018-01-01  03:00:00
4   AA  2018-01-01  04:00:00
5   AA  2018-01-01  05:00:00
6   AA  2018-01-01  06:00:00
7   AA  2018-01-01  07:00:00
8   AA  2018-01-01  08:00:00
9   AA  2018-01-01  09:00:00
```

However, the data type is still an object type:

```
df.dtypes
>>> site            object
    date    datetime64[ns]
    time            object
    dtype: object
```

But, when I check the type for individual value, it does seem to work:

```
df.at[5,'time']
>>> datetime.time(5, 0)

type(df.at[5,'time'])
>>> datetime.time
```

Still, I can't filter the data based on time:

```
from datetime import time
df[df['time'].between_time(time(5),time(8))]
>>> TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex
```

Comment: pandas has no separate data types for 'date' and 'time', there's only datetime. Use a datetime index as @SomeDude suggests below to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see TypeError is because in the documentation for [`between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between_time.html) it clearly says:

> Raises
>
> ```
> TypeError
>
>     If the index is not a DatetimeIndex
> ```

You need to set the index for the dataframe as datetime index, but for that to happen your data for the index should contain datetime not just time. By using `time()` you are converting it into `time` object. But DatetimeIndex needs a datetime object.

One way to get the result you wanted is:

```
df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(
    pd.to_datetime(df["time"], format="%H%M"))).between_time(
    time(5), time(8)
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  site        date  time
0   AA  2018-01-01  0500
1   AA  2018-01-01  0600
2   AA  2018-01-01  0700
3   AA  2018-01-01  0800
```

Or even you could use your `date` column to create a datetime index and then use `between_time` like:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])).between_time(
    time(5), time(8)).reset_index(drop=True)
```